# Getting incorrect start and end dates from weekOfYear

Tags: ios, swift, date

When I run this code:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
    dateComponents.weekOfYear = 2
    dateComponents.year = 2017
    let startOfWeek = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
    let endOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: startOfWeek!)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    print(formatter.string(from: startOfWeek!))
    print(formatter.string(from: endOfWeek!))
```

It prints this:

```
1/8/17
    1/14/17
```

When I change the code to this:

```
dateComponents.weekOfYear = 1
    dateComponents.year = 2017
```

It prints this:

```
12/31/17
    1/6/18
```

Why is it 12/31/17?

Comment: try without making short formats, print out full date

Comment: Use [`yearForWeekOfYear `](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponents/1779818-yearforweekofyear) instead of `year` when working with `weekOfYear`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I use `.full` style to print the dates, I get Sunday, December 31, 2017 for the first date, but it's obviously wrong because December 31 is a Thursday.

If you want to get the correct date, use `yearForWeekOfYear` instead of `year`. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponents/1779818-yearforweekofyear):

> You can use the yearForWeekOfYear property with the weekOfYear and weekday properties to get the date corresponding to a particular weekday of a given week of a year. For example, the 6th day of the 53rd week of the year 2005 (ISO 2005-W53-6) corresponds to Sat 1 January 2005 on the Gregorian calendar.

Alternative, you can be a little naughty and not listen to the docs and use weekOfYear = 54:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
dateComponents.weekOfYear = 54
dateComponents.year = 2017
let startOfWeek = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
let endOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: startOfWeek!)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .short
print(formatter.string(from: startOfWeek!))
print(formatter.string(from: endOfWeek!))
```

This prints:

```
1/1/17
1/7/17
```

which is coincidentally, the correct dates.